# INSERT IGNORE Inserting 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, rows

When I am attempting to run "INSERT IGNORE ..." in MYSQL to add only one variable to a table of several options, after the first insert, it refuses to work.  It says "Inserted rows: 0" and doesn't insert my new value into the database.  I believe this is because there is already an entry with a "nothing" value and MYSQL doesn't allow the empty field to be duplicated.  This seems to be odd behavior (as long as the two inserts are not exactly the same), so I am wondering if there is some way to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `INSERT` do not have to be exactly the same, they just have to be the same for the primary key columns.

`INSERT IGNORE` will ignore an insert if there is already a row with the same primary key.
If you did `INSERT` instead of `INSERT IGNORE`, you would be getting an error (duplicate primary key).

If you want to instead update the existing row, you can use `REPLACE`.

Either way, there can be only one row for each primary key.

Comment: Thanks Thilo!  I edited the field that is the primary key, and it works great now!